# How to know if tag already display in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my Code:

```
<template v-for="day in getMonthLength()" >
          
          <td :id='notempty' v-for="dataa in data" v-if="dataa.employee_id === employee.id">
            <input type="number" :value="dataa.value">
          </td>

          <td :id='empty'>
            <input type="number">
          </td>

</template>
```

So if the td-Tag with the id "notempty" is displayed (v-if is one time true) in the `<template>`-loop run
the td with the id "empty" should not be displayed (ignored/not interpreted) in the `<template>`-loop run. And if the "notempty" td tag doesnt display (every v-if is false in the td-loop), the empty tag should be display

V-Else in the "empty" td tag like below doesnt work, becuase of the v-for in the td "notempty".  the empty td tag would be displayed everytime the employee.id is not equal.

```
 <template v-for="day in getMonthLength()" >
              
              <td :id='notempty' v-for="dataa in data" v-if="dataa.employee_id === employee.id">
                <input type="number" :value="dataa.value">
              </td>
    
              <td v-else :id='empty'> <---------
                <input type="number">
              </td>
    
    </template>
```

Comment: what about setting `id` dynamically due to your condition? then you won't need second `td` tag. also same thing for `:value`

Comment: @MohammadMirsafaei that is a good idea thanks, but how i can bind :value on a condition or how to set it dynamically to my v-if

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<template>` again. Do not forget to place `:key` on elements generated with `v-for`

```html
<template v-for="day in getMonthLength()" >
  <template v-for="dataa in data">
    <td :id='notempty' v-if="dataa.employee_id === employee.id" :key="dataa.employee_id">
      <input type="number" :value="dataa.value">
    </td>
    <td v-else :id='empty' :key="dataa.employee_id">
      <input type="number">
    </td>
  </template>
</template>
```